# NLTK - how to find out what corpora are installed from within python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I'm trying to load some corpora I installed with the NLTK installer but I got a:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import machado
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      ImportError: cannot import name machado
```

But in the download manager (`nltk.download()`) the package machado is marked as installed and I have a `nltk_data/corpus/machado` folder.

How can I see from inside the python intepreter what are the installed corpora?

Also, what package should I install to work with this how-to?
http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/portuguese_en.html

I can't find the module `nltk.examples` refered to in the how-to.

Comment: mine was at /home/myUser/nltk_data

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try

```
import nltk.corpus
dir(nltk.corpus)
```

at which point, it probably told you something about `__LazyModule__...` so do `dir(nltk.corpus)` again.

If that doesn't work, try tab-completion in iPython.

Comment: This method will not tell you what corpora are _installed_ in the nltk data directory; only which ones have predefined access points whether they are installed or not.

Comment: If you want to see if a corpus is installed I recommend this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925041/how-to-check-if-wordnet-is-already-installed

Answer (score 7):

The NLTK includes a package, `nltk.corpus`, that contains definitions of corpus readers (such as `PlainTextCorpusReader`). This package also includes a large list of pre-defined access points for corpora that can be downloaded with `nltk.downloader()`. These access points (e.g., `nltk.corpus.brown`) are defined whether or not the corresponding corpus has been downloaded.

1. To see **which access points are defined** in the NLTK, use `dir(nltk.corpus)` (after `import nltk`).
2. To see **which corpora you have** in your `nltk_data` area, try this:

   ```
   import os
   import nltk
   print( os.listdir( nltk.data.find("corpora") ) )
   ```

   This just dumps a list with the contents of the folder `nltk_data/corpora`. You can take it from there.
3. If **you have installed your own corpus** in the `nltk_data/corpora` area and the NLTK doesn't know about it, you need to fire up the appropriate reader yourself. E.g., if it's a plaintext corpus in `corpora/mycorpus` and all the files end in `.txt`, you'd do it like this:

   ```
   import nltk
   from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader

   mypath = nltk.data.find("corpora/mycorpus")
   mycorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(mypath, r".*\.txt$")
   ```

   But in that case you could put your own corpus anywhere, and point `mypath` to it directly instead of asking the NLTK to find it.