# How to check if wordnet is already installed?

Tags: nltk

I know that we can check for resources like this:

```py
try:
  nltk.data.find('tokenizers/punkt')
except LookupError:
  nltk.download('punkt')
```

But I can't find the way to do this for wordnet:

```py
try:
  nltk.data.find('wordnet') # ????/wordnet
except LookupError:
  nltk.download('wordnet')
```

How can I make this check?

Comment: Try `nltk.download('popular')`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211525/how-do-i-download-nltk-data Alternatively, there's `pip install -U wn` https://github.com/alvations/wordnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```py
nltk.find('corpora/wordnet')
```

Comment: hi, can you share the documentation table for this, i could not seem to find a clear list of each

Comment: i am not sure about the doc, but you can have an exhaustive table of available data with this command: `python -c "import nltk; nltk.download()"`